# Extract data from indeterminate range size in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to VBA, and I'd love some help.

I have a spreadsheet that has a range that will always have 10 columns, but could have X amount of rows.  I'm trying to write a VBA script that will iterate over this range and extract the values out of each cell.

For example, if I have 2 rows I need A1, B1, C1..J1 and then I need A2, B2, C2...J2.  The next time I could have 5 rows and then another time 3.

How do I setup my loop to make this work?

Comment: To determine the last used row: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10642588/829571

Comment: YOu can also determine the last row by using `UsedRange.Rows.Count` if it is not a column specific row count.

Comment: How about assigning `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value` to a Variant variable and then iterating through that? Is that possible?

Comment: @Mark: I will never recommend using `UsedRange` as they are highly unreliable in finding the last row in a worksheet. Use this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
Dim lastRow as long

lastRow = UsedRange.Rows.Count     'or some other way of determining the last row used

    for i = 1 to lastRow    'loop through all used rows

    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).value    'column A
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).value    'column B
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).value    'column C

    next i
```

Comment: Excellent! I used this with the "UsedRange.Rows.Count" suggested above.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. As already said by Siddharth, UsedRange.Rows.Count is not a good way of finding the last row of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a dynamic named range and loop through that. See this [link](http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2010/08/17/excel-dynamic-named-ranges-never-manually-updating-your-charts-2/) or google for better examples. Dynamic name ranges are powerful, especially for charts.

For your example you would set the name range reference to;

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),10) '10 is the width and will go to column J
```

assuming that column A will have the true max row of the table.

Then;

```
Dim arr() As Variant

 arr = Range("YourRangeName")

  For x = 1 To UBound(arr,1) 'Finds the max number of rows in the array, UBound(arr,2) finds the total columns.
    'Do some code here where x steps through the array arr
    '  = arr(x, 1) 'column a
    '  = arr(x,2)  'column b 
    '  = arr(x,3) ....     
  Next x
```

It's almost always better/faster to process as much as you can in code, i.e. assigning a range in Excel to an Array then loop through the array rather than referencing cells (especially in a loops).